# Como adicionar dados em uma lista sempre que uma <p:hotkey> for utilizada?

Tags: jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho um `<p:hotkey>` que é o componente do Primefaces para se trabalhar com atalhos. Toda vez que aperto <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> dois novos campos aparecem na página porém gostaria de toda vez que apertar essa combinação os dados que estão nos `imputText` `Codigo` e `Descrição` sejam adicionados em uma lista.

Por exemplo, eu aperto <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> dois campos novos aparecem e os valores dos primeiros campos são adicionados em uma lista. Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

Campos:

```jsp
<p:outputLabel value="Código Serviço" />
<p:inputText id="codigoServico" size="40" value="#{cadastroReembolsoBean.servico.codServico}"/>

<p:outputLabel value="Descrição" />
<p:inputText id="descricaoServico" size="46" value="#{cadastroReembolsoBean.servico.descricao}"/>
```

Hotkey:

```jsp
<p:hotkey bind="ctrl+1" handler="desenvolvimento()"></p:hotkey>
<p:remoteCommand name="desenvolvimento"
    action="#{cadastroReembolsoBean.adicionarCodigos()}" immediate="true" 
    update="pnlCadastroServico"></p:remoteCommand>
```

Método `adicionarCodigos`:

```java
public void adicionarCodigos() {
    if (contador < 0) {
        contador = 0;
    }

    solicitacao.getListaServicos().add(servico);
    System.out.println("Serviço Adicionado: "+solicitacao.getListaServicos());

    contador++; 
}
```

Notem que tenho um `System.out.println` que mostra a `listaServicos`, porem ela está vindo nula. Ou seja, não esta pegando os valores do `imputText`. Como consigo pegar esses valores ao entrar com o atalho?

Comment: Só pra confirmar se entendi... Quando usar o atalho vai preencher o item com os dados dos `input` e o mesmo item vai ser adicionado na lista?

Comment: Quando eu uso o atalho ele pega os dados do input e joga numa lista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve informar ao `form` quais dados serão sincronizados *Interface > Bean*

Para isso serve o atributo `process` onde você informa o ID dos componentes que serão "sincronizados".

Para mais detalhes, veja a resposta do mago do JSF na versão em inglês do Stack: [Diferença entre process e update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25347186/3083143)

Acredito que essa é a chave para resolução do seu problema, de acordo com o descrito. 
Inclusive, poderia utilizar somente o `p:hotkey`:

```
<p:hotkey bind="ctrl+1" 
    actionListener="#{cadastroReembolsoBean.adicionarCodigos()}"    
    update="pnlCadastroServico"
    process="@this codigoServico descricaoServico">
</p:hotkey>
```

Comment: Olá, @info.sistemas! Vejo que é sua primeira resposta no site. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona o Stack Overflow. No seu caso, tente editar a resposta para ficar mais parecida com uma resposta direta ao problema do nosso colega, pois o que escreveu encaixa-se mais como um comentário.

Comment: @Dherik, você tinha razão. Editei e formatei conforme uma resposta. Obrigado pelo feedback.

Comment: Muito obrigado @info.sistemas acho que estava faltando o `process` mesmo.

Comment: @info.sistemas essa foi boa "mago do JSF". Concordo contigo. rsrs

Comment: @info.sistemas, começou bem! :D. Bem-vindo!